# Show that on the interval $(0,\alpha)$, where $\alpha \in (0, \pi]$, $\cos(\theta) = \cos (\alpha - \theta)$ at precisely one point.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

As part of a problem I am working on, I need to demonstrate that the following two functions intersect at precisely one point:

> For $\alpha \in (0, \pi]$, consider the functions: \begin{align} \\
> &\cos_1 : (0,\alpha) \to [-1,1], \text{ with the mapping rule }\cos_1(\theta)=\cos(\theta) \\  &\cos_2:  (0,\alpha) \to [-1,1], \text{ with the mapping rule }\cos_2(\theta)=\cos_1(\alpha - \theta)=\cos(\alpha-\theta) \end{align}

i.e. they are just relative shifted trig-functions of the same frequency observed over the interval $(0, \alpha)$.

At the moment, the only approach I could think of **uses calculus** and works as follows:

The derivative of $\cos_2$ can be written as: $\cos_2 '(\theta)=-\sin(\alpha - \theta)\cdot(-1)=\sin(\alpha - \theta)$ and the derivative of $\cos_1$ can be written as $-\sin(\theta)$.

Given these derivatives, we know that over the interval $(0,\alpha)$, $\cos_2$ is *strictly increasing* and $\cos_1$ is *strictly decreasing*. Further, it is also apparent that $\cos_1(\theta) = \cos_2(\theta)$ when $\theta = \frac{\alpha}{2}$.

I next made the following (general) lemma that reads as:

> For a function $f$ and a function $g$, if $f$ is strictly decreasing on some interval $I$ and $g$ is strictly increasing on the same interval $I$, and it is known that there is an $x^*$ for which $f(x^*) = g(x^*)$, then there exists no other $y \neq x^*$ such that $f(y)=g(y)$. i.e. $x^*$ is the only point in $I$ where the functions are equal.

Briefly, the proof works by contradiction. Suppose there is a $y \in I$ where $y \neq x^*$ such that $f(y)=g(y)$. Either $y \lt x^*$ or $y \gt x^*$. Suppose the former. By assumption:

If $y \lt x^*$, then $f(y) \gt f(x^*)$ and $g(y) \lt g(x^*)$...because $f$ is strictly decreasing and $g$ is strictly increasing. However, $g(y)=f(y) \gt f(x^*)=g(x^*)$. This implies that $g(y) \gt g(x^*)$, which is a contradiction. A similar argument works for $y \gt x^*$. Therefore, we conclude that $x^*$ is the only such point in $I$ where $f$ and $g$ are equal.

Applying this lemma to my particular trig case, I have proven that over the interval $(0, \alpha)$, $\cos_1$ only equals $\cos_2$ at one point: $\theta = \frac{\alpha}{2}$.

**Although I believe this proof is fine**, it struck me as possibly overkill. Do I really need calculus to prove this statement? I feel as though there is a simpler argument that does not require me to invoke calculus.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use the fact that $$\cos(\alpha-\theta)=\cos\alpha\cos\theta+\sin\alpha\sin\theta$$

and break it into two cases.

Case 1: Suppose $\alpha=\pi$. Then $\cos\theta=\cos(\pi-\theta)=-\cos\theta$, which has the only solution in our interval $\theta=\pi/2$.

Case 2: Suppose $\alpha\neq\pi$. Suppose, to the contrary, that $\theta=\pi/2$. If $\cos(\pi/2)=\cos(\alpha-\pi/2)$, then

$$0=0\cos\alpha+1\sin\alpha\implies\alpha=\pi,$$

which is a contradiction, so we know $\theta\neq\pi/2$. Now

\begin{align*}
\cos\theta=\cos(\alpha-\theta)&\iff\cos\theta=\cos\alpha\cos\theta+\sin\alpha\sin\theta\\
&\iff\cos\theta(1-\cos\alpha)=\sin\alpha\sin\theta\\
&\iff\tan\theta=\frac{1-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}=\tan\frac\alpha2\\
\end{align*}

The solutions to this equation are of the form $\theta=n\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\tan\frac\alpha2\right)$, where $n\in\mathbb Z$. Since $\alpha\in(0,\pi)$, this simplifies to $\theta=n\pi+\frac\alpha2$. Therefore, the only valid solution is $\theta=\frac\alpha2$.

Comment: Very nice - for anyone reading this, Bonnaduck rules out $\pi/2$ to begin with in case 2 because $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})$ is undefined.  Also, note that because $\alpha \in (0, \pi)$ in case 2, $\frac{\alpha}{2}$ is necessarily positive which means for $n \geq 1$, $\theta$ would be greater than $\pi$, which is a no-no.